# Unable to find the distance between the centroid of a census tract and school location coordinates

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidycensus)
library(sf)
library(sp)
#install.packages('geosphere')
library('geosphere')
library(rgeos)
library(sfheaders)
#install.packages('reshape')
library('reshape')
#> Linking to GEOS 3.6.1, GDAL 2.1.3, PROJ 4.9.3

census_tract <- get_acs(geography = "tract", 
                  variables = "B19013_001",
                  state = "CA", 
                  county = c("San Joaquin","Merced","stanislaus"), 
                  geometry = TRUE, 
                  year = 2020)


plot(st_geometry(census_tract), axes = T)
plot(st_centroid(st_geometry(census_tract)), pch = "+", col = "red", add = T)



library(ggplot2)
ggplot(census_tract) + geom_sf() +
  geom_sf(aes(geometry = st_centroid(st_geometry(census_tract))), colour = "red")
census_tract$centroid <- st_centroid(st_geometry(census_tract))

schoolloc <- read.csv("C:/Users/rlnu/Desktop/EXAMPLE/pubschls.csv")
schoolloc <- schoolloc%>% filter(County == c("San Joaquin","Merced","Stanislaus"))

census_tract <- census_tract %>%
  mutate(long = unlist(map(census_tract$centroid,1)),
         lat = unlist(map(census_tract$centroid,2)))  
shortest_distance$min_distance <- expand.grid.df(census_tract,schoolloc) %>%
  mutate(distance = distHaversine(p1 = cbind(long,lat),
                                  p2 = cbind(Longitude,Latitude)) 
`
```

I am trying to find distance between the each census tract's  centroid to three nearest schools. please help me out with it. I have written some code . The logic is wrong and the code is not working

Answer (score 0):

Can achieve this using the sf package.

I could not access you schools data so made a dummy set of 4 schools.

```
library(sf)


schools <- data.frame(School_Name=c("School_1", "School_2", "School_3", "School_4"), Lat=c(37.83405, 38.10867, 37.97743, 37.51615), Long=c(-121.2810, -121.2312, -121.2575, -120.8772)) %>% st_as_sf(coords=c("Long", "Lat"), crs=4326)
```

Convert tracts to centroids and make the crs the same as the school set then calculate the distance matrix

```
census_centroid <- st_centroid(census_tract)  %>% st_transform(4326)

DISTS<- st_distance(census_centroid, schools)
```

Rename the columns to be the school IDs

```
colnames(DISTS) <- schools$School_Name
```

link it back to centoids

```
cent_dists <- cbind(census_centroid, DISTS) %>% #bind ditances to centroids
  pivot_longer(cols = -names(census_centroid), names_to = "School Name", values_to = "Distance") %>% #make long for ordering
  group_by(NAME) %>% #group by centroid
  slice_min(Distance,n= 3) %>% # take three closest
  mutate(Near_No=paste0("Near_School_",rep(1:3))) #School distance ranking
```

Make wide if one row per census centroid desired, might want to play with column order though

```
cent_dists_wide <- cent_dists %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = c("Near_No"), values_from = c("Distance", "School Name"), names_sort = FALSE) #make wid if wyou want one row per centoid
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I am still unable to find errors  generated  by your code . Here is the school data available in this link [link] (https://www.cde.ca.gov/ds/si/ds/pubschls.asp)